# Type mismatch at match ... case

Tags: scala

Here is a simplified version of code I have:

```
class MyClass(a: Int)

def method1: Option[List[MyClass]] = {
  val response = getData

  val res = response match {
    case Left(_)
         | Right(Class1(None))
         | Right(Class1(Some(Class2(_, _, Nil)))) => None
    case Right(Class1(Some(Class2(_, _, xs: Seq[Class3])))) => xs map { x => new MyClass(x.someVal) }
  }

  Some(res)
}
```

It complains

```
found   : Equals
[error]  required: List[MyClass]
[error]    Some(res)
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What type does `getData` return?

Comment: You may want to re-think the signature of `method1`, unless you have a good reason for forcing clients to have separate processing when there are no results. Simply `List[MyClass]` is usually more appropriate, where the returned result has zero or more items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative solution you can wrap the second case into `Option` or `Some`:

```
 val res = response match {
    case Left(_)
         | Right(Class1(None))
         | Right(Class1(Some(Class2(_, _, Nil)))) => None
    case Right(Class1(Some(Class2(_, _, xs: Seq[Class3])))) => Option(xs map { x => new MyClass(x.someVal)) }
  }
```

and remove `Some(res)` at the end

Comment: What's the difference between `Option(xs map { x => new MyClass(x.someVal)) }` and `Some(xs map { x => new MyClass(x.someVal)) }` ?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Nothing helpful in your case: `def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)`, it returns `None` if the arg is `null`. But in some cases if you deal with Java it can be useful

Comment: @MariusKavansky: There is another difference, also not useful in this case: type inference. With `Some(a)` you get `Some[A]`, with `Option(a)` you get `Option[A]`. So in some cases you have to specify type manually (for instance in `foldLeft(Some(1): Option[Int])`). I prefer `a.some` method from `scalaz`, it returns an `Option`.

Answer (score 4):

You should replace `None` with `Nil` in the first `case`.

Common type of `Option` and `List` is `Equals`, so the result of `x match { case ... => None case ... => List() }` is `Equals`, not `List`.

You should also call `toList` after `map` in the second `case`, otherwise you'll get `Seq`, not `List`.